# Why does Javascript/Vite.js multi-page app fail on build?

Tags: javascript, vite

**This question was updated on Nov. 20, see comments below for context**

I'm building a multi-page app using HTML/Javascript and Vite. Everything is working perfectly in development and production servers -- until I need to access pages that require the user to be logged in. I'm able to navigate to the login page and successfully login...but then when I try to route the logged in user to the `home.html` page, I encounter a problem.

When add `home.html` to my config file, the build breaks. I get an error saying:
`[vite:build-html] EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read file: /Users/mickeyvershbow/Documents/coding/vite-projects/ekkobar-app/vite-web-app/pages/home/home.html error during build: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory`

It seems like there must something wrong with the way I'm specifying the entry point in my config file, but I don't know how to address this and can't find any info on this in the [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app). Is there a plugin I need to use? Some middleware?

File structure:

```
├── package.json
├── vite.config.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── styles.css
├── pages
│   ├── login
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── login.js
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── home.html **requires user to be logged in
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │
```

vite.config.js

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { defineConfig } = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        login: resolve(__dirname, "pages/login/login.html"),
        home: resolve(__dirname, "pages/home/home.html"),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: What do you use to generate your project file structure?

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure you have shared in the question shows that your login and home pages are ***present inside you pages folder***. Hence you will have to provide valid path to your vite to include the files present in the folder.

Your folder path now becomes **"pages/login/index.html"** and **"pages/home/index.html"**

Please find the updated vite config below.

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { defineConfig } = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
                login: resolve(__dirname, "pages/login/index.html"),
                home: resolve(__dirname, "pages/home/index.html"),
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so when I try this, I get a different but similar error, saying the module "home" cannot be resolved. The homepage requires a user to be logged in, so I figured maybe that's the issue, and commented it out. I'm new to working with modules so I'm not sure how this works. Now I get a different error saying "Rollup failed to resolve import "style.css" from "index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:"

Can you advise?

Comment: Basically vite cannot find the css file you referenced in html if you fail to give the valid relative path. Use ./<dirName>/styles.css to refer your css file in html

Example : Assuming that my css stays in home folder

home -> styles.css

In index.html you would refer to this file using this path ./home/styles.css

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I cleared this error and the server runs, but then when I try to open in browser, I get a 404 `cannot get ./pages/login/login.html` error. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I updated my question to include my updated config file, as well as my app.yaml....note that I'm setting the entry point as `/login.html` and not `/index.html` due to how I've named the files in my app.

Comment: I can link to github if that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'm working on recreating the issue in a public repo (the one I'm working on is private) and will share. Quick update: I made a rookie mistake and didn't realize I needed to run `npm run build` in order for `npm run serve` to work. So that cleared the 404 error on the login page, which now works. However the `home.html` page requires a user to be logged in, and when I add that to my config, I get the following build error: `[vite:build-html] EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory`. The error is referencing the home page that requires the user to be logged in.

Comment: [...continued from prev comment] Do I need to add something to the config to handle this kind of user auth issue? I'm not finding anything in the docs. 

And again, working on a repo for you, thanks for patience on that.

Comment: Not sure if this plugin is relevant? https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/auth

Comment: did you figure it out?
My guess is that you may have to modiffy your entry point file, and adjust the `root` option in your vite config, to point where you want it to be. I'd like to know if there's another way, but you may have to point your root to the /src/pages folder, and put every pages in there.